# Pop up message and a button to cancel it

Tags: javascript

My site contains two pages. The front and an article. I want to add a pop up message whenever someone visit the front page. This pop up will have a link that will trasfer the user in the article.The article will contain a button that when is clicked it means that the user no longer want this pop up message so it must be stopped for this user only. Any idea how can i do this? should i write html & javascript? php?and where can i find the pages in order to edit them?

Comment: `The article will contain a button that when is clicked it means that the user no longer want this pop up message so it must be stopped for this user only.` You need to use jQuery with cookies, so when the user clicks the button it saves the cookie. Then you create a condition if cookie exists then you don't show popup in your jQuery.

Comment: thanks for the answer but also i do not know where should i add the javascript/jquery code. should i create one file?

Comment: In your theme's folder there is a .info file, you can add there `scripts[] = js/myscript.js` then put myscript in the js folder.

Comment: also make sure you wrap your jquery code like this `(function ($) { // custom code goes here })(jQuery);`

Comment: there are other methods besides the .info file way to add your script, see https://www.drupal.org/node/171213